# Are there any female characters in Arrow whom Oliver Queen didn't have a relationship with?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow, sexuality

In CW's Arrow, Oliver Queen has been in a relationship with practically every female character at some point or another.

The only female characters I can think of whom he was never in a relationship with are either close family or dead.

> **Immediate family**
>  - Thea Queen
>  
>  **Dead**
>  - The Mayor
>  
>  **Immediate family AND dead**
>  - Moria Queen

### Are there any living female characters in Arrow (not including immediate family) whom Oliver Queen didn't have a relationship with?

Comment: hmmm, you and your ubiquitous list questions. ¬_¬

Comment: @RedCaio C'mon I really don't think that this is a big list. Maybe two or three names.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arrow_characters

Comment: diggles wife, the end. or diggles wife, female officer 2, chyna white

Comment: @Cherubel Is China White still alive?

Comment: And katana too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma She also might be dead.

Comment: @ibid cant remember now that yo ask. she is there in the flashbacks. maybe she finaly dies at the end of s3

Comment: @ibid i haven't seen the latest episode, anyways DCEU is killing all suicide squad character. So she can be dead soon if not yet.

Comment: LOL I have to give you a +1 for the sheer hilariousness of the question.

Answer (score 10):

- Lyla Michaels.

  > Digles' partner
- Donna Smoak,

  > Felicity's mother.
- Chien Na Wei / China White,

  > a Chinese Triad leader who seeks revenge against Arrow
- Cindy a.k.a. "Sin",

  > a wayward youth who Sara takes under her wing in Starling City
- Tatsu Yamashiro / Katana,

  > The wife of Maseo Yamashiro and mother of his son
- Dinah Drake Lance,

  > mother of Laurel and Sara, and former wife of Quentin

Comment: Not to spoil recent episodes, but at least one of these characters is dead. Possibly three of them.

Comment: Oliver was in a relationship with Nyssa during season 3. They even had a wedding ceremony IIRC.

Comment: This was just from a quick look through the wiki page Richard shared. I didn't get far with the guest appearances though. Feel free to add more by clicking the [edit] link.

Comment: How about subtract? Several of these don't meet my criteria.

Comment: **Spoiler aheadt** :removed two, one is wife as per league of assassin's rule and other is dead.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Anyone know if China White or Katana are dead?

Comment: @ibid i have to see last 2 episode for katana's status , for China White i forgot what happens in the end.